# JNI Bus error after moving object creation to another method

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a problem with JNI that has taken me all day and will probably drive me insane if I don't call for help.

**In two phrases**: I call a NewObject from a JNI method and it works fine, but when I moved this code to another method, it crashes.

**More details:**

I have this simple class, and I want to create instances of it from the JNI C/C++ code:

```
package example;

public class ModelDetails {
    public ModelDetails() { ... }
}
```

The class with the native method is as follows:

```
package example;
public class JNIWrapper {
     public native ModelDetails getModelDetails() throws SomeException;
}
```

The following code worked very nicely:

```
jclass    modelDetailsClass           = NULL;
jmethodID modelDetailsConstMid        = NULL;

JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_example_JNIWrapper_getModelDetails
 (JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj) {

    cout << "getModelDetails c++" << endl;

    // ModelDetails class
    if (!modelDetailsClass) { // reuse class
        modelDetailsClass = env->FindClass("example/ModelDetails");
    }
    if (!modelDetailsClass) { // check if findclass was successful
        throwJavaException(env, "Could not get class ModelDetails");
        return NULL;
    }
    cout << "model detail class: " << modelDetailsClass << endl;

    // constructor
    if (!modelDetailsConstMid) { // reuse method id
        modelDetailsConstMid = env->GetMethodID(modelDetailsClass, "<init>", "()V");
    }
    if (!modelDetailsConstMid) { // check if getmethodid was successful
        throwJavaException(env, "Could not get ModelDetails constructor method id");
        return NULL;
    }

    // create object
    jobject mdetails = env->NewObject(modelDetailsClass, modelDetailsConstMid);
    if (!mdetails) {
        throwJavaException(env, "Could not create ModelDetails instance");
        return NULL;
    }
    return mdetails;
}
```

However, since I have to do a lot of things in this function `Java_example_JNIWrapper_getModelDetails`, I decided to move the creation of this object to another function:

```
jobject fillModelDetails(JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj) {
    cout << "fillModelDetails" << endl;

    // ModelDetails class
    if (!modelDetailsClass) { // reuse class
        modelDetailsClass = env->FindClass("example/ModelDetails");
    }
    if (!modelDetailsClass) { // check if findclass was successful
        throwJavaException(env, "Could not get class ModelDetails");
        return NULL;
    }
    cout << "model detail class: " << modelDetailsClass << endl;

    // constructor
    if (!modelDetailsConstMid) { // reuse method id
        modelDetailsConstMid = env->GetMethodID(modelDetailsClass, "<init>", "()V");
    }
    if (!modelDetailsConstMid) { // check if getmethodid was successful
        throwJavaException(env, "Could not get ModelDetails constructor method id");
        return NULL;
    } 

    // create object
    jobject mdetails = env->NewObject(modelDetailsClass, modelDetailsConstMid);
    if (!mdetails) {
        throwJavaException(env, "Could not create ModelDetails instance");
        return NULL;
    }

    return mdetails;
}
```

This way, in `Java_example_JNIWrapper_getModelDetails` I just call `fillModelDetails(env, jobj);`

The problem is that now I get a bus error at the `NewObject` line.

```
Invalid memory access of location 0x9 eip=0x475fe1
```

**Question**:
Does anyone know why I should not be calling a constructor from another method? It seems really weird.

Thanks for any tip, idea, comments...

---

**Edit:**

I've just added `-Xcheck:jni` and got this error:

```
FATAL ERROR in native method: Bad global or local ref passed to JNI
at example.JNIWrapper.getModelDetails(Native Method)
```

So this gave me the idea that the problem might be caused by using the constructor and class id from a global variable. I moved these declarations to a local variable in the JNI method and it works.

This really astonishes me because I've been using these global variables from some time now and never had any problems... what could be causing this problem?

Comment: You should attach a debugger and find out exactly where you are getting the fault.

Comment: I did that, it's exactly at the NewObject call.

Comment: What were the values of env, modelDetailsClass, and the mid? that '9' suggests a 0 in env.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will answer this since I found the problem, however another question remains regarding re-using the `jclass` and `jmethodID`. Changing this question in that direction does not seem organized, so I will open another thread.

The solution was to use local variables for

```
jclass    modelDetailsClass           = NULL;
jmethodID modelDetailsConstMid        = NULL;
```

instead of the global variables that I was using before.

Comment: You have observed it nearly correctly: But the jmethodID is not the problem, it is always the same integer value and you can store it in a static variable. The problem is caused only by the jclass which is garbage collected when your JNI code goes back to Java.

Comment: And you did not study thorougly why it works once and fails another time. It has nothing to do if you execute the code in one function or in another function. The cause is that you leave JNI code, go back to Java, where the garbage collector runs and then you call JNI again where your static jclass variable is not valid anymore. The cause of the problem is that you store a local reference of jclass (which is subject to garbage collection) in a static C++ variable. All local references are only valid for one JNI function call. When JNI returns to Java all local references become invalid.

Answer (score 0):

This question answers the underlying issue:

[Why I should not reuse a jclass and/or jmethodID in JNI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093112/why-i-should-not-reuse-a-jclass-and-or-jmethodid-in-jni)

Comment: It is indeed the "[an]other thread" mentioned by @YuppieNetworking in his own answer :-)