# Why I should not reuse a jclass and/or jmethodID in JNI?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

This is a question related to [a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088171/jni-bus-error-after-moving-object-creation-to-another-method), but this post was solved and now I wanted to change the direction of the question.

When working with JNI, it is necessary to ask the `JNIEnv` object for `jclass` and `jmethodID` for each class and method that will be used in the C/C++ code. Just to be clear, I want to call Java contructors or methods from C/C++.

Since the communication from Java to C/C++ (and viceversa) is costly, I initially thought that one way to minimize this was to reuse the `jclass` and `jmethodID`. Therefore, I saved this instances in global variables as follows:

```
jclass    someClass  = NULL;
jmethodID someMethod = NULL;

JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_example_method1(JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj) {
    // initialize someClass and someMethod if they are NULL
    // use someClass and someMethod to call java (for example, thru NewObject)
}

JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_example_method2(JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj) {
    // initialize someClass and someMethod if they are NULL
    // use someClass and someMethod to call java again
}
```

A more specific (and useful) example, which I use to throw exceptions from anywhere in my JNI functions:

```
jclass    jniExceptionClass           = NULL;

void throwJavaException(JNIEnv *env, const char* msg) {
    if (!jniExceptionClass) {
        jniExceptionClass = env->FindClass("example/JNIRuntimeException");
    }
    if (jniExceptionClass)
        env->ThrowNew(jniExceptionClass, msg);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I continued to use this *pattern* and got a segmentation fault that was only solved by not-reusing this variables (this was the solution to the previous post).

The questions are:

- Why is it illegal to reuse the `jclass` and `jmethodID` thru different JNI functions? I thought that this values were always the same.
- Just for curiosity: what is the impact/overhead of initializing all necessary `jclass` and `jmethodID` for each JNI function?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The rules here are clear. Method ID and field ID values are forever. You can hang onto them. The lookups take some time.

`jclass`, on the other hand, is generally a *local reference*. A local reference survives, at most, the duration of a single call to a JNI function.

If you need to optimize, you have to ask the JVM to make a global reference for you. It's not uncommon to acquire and keep references to common classes like `java.lang.String`.

Holding such a reference to a class will prevent it (the class) from being garbage-collected, of course.

```
jclass local = env->FindClass(CLS_JAVA_LANG_STRING);
_CHECK_JAVA_EXCEPTION(env);
java_lang_string_class = (jclass)env->NewGlobalRef(local);
_CHECK_JAVA_EXCEPTION(env);
env->DeleteLocalRef(local);
_CHECK_JAVA_EXCEPTION(env);
```

The check macro calls:

```
static inline void
check_java_exception(JNIEnv *env, int line)
{
    UNUSED(line);
    if(env->ExceptionOccurred()) {
#ifdef DEBUG
        fprintf(stderr, "Java exception at rlpjni.cpp line %d\n", line);
        env->ExceptionDescribe();
    abort();
#endif
        throw bt_rlpjni_java_is_upset();
    }
}
```

Comment: JNI automatically cleans up the local references returned by `FindClass` when going back to the Java side.

Comment: in this link ( http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/other.html ), they use NewWeakGlobalRef. I will try with the weak reference.

Comment: @bmargulies would you please share your code for _CHECK_JAVA_EXCEPTION? Thanks :-).

Comment: Method and field IDs are not forever. They may be invalidated if the class is unloaded, so you're advised to keep a reference to the class as well. Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#accessing_fields_and_methods

Answer (score 11):

As others already wrote

1. You can store `jmethodID` in a static C++ variable without problems
2. You can store local `jobject` or `jclass` in a static C++ variable after converting them to global objects by calling `env->NewGloablRef()`

I just want to add an additional information here:
The major reason for storing jclass in a static C++ variable will be that you think it is a performance issue to call `env->FindClass()` each time.

But I **measured the speed** of `FindClass()` with a performance counter with the `QueryPerformanceCounter()` API on Windows. And the result was astonishing:

On my computer with a 3,6 GHz CPU the execution of

```
jcass p_Container = env->FindClass("java/awt/Container");
```

takes between 0,01 ms and 0,02 ms. That is incredibly fast. I looked into the Java source code and they use a Dictionary where the classes are stored. This seems to be implemented very efficiently.

I tested some more classes and here is the result:

```
Elapsed 0.002061 ms for java/net/URL
Elapsed 0.044390 ms for java/lang/Boolean
Elapsed 0.019235 ms for java/lang/Character
Elapsed 0.018372 ms for java/lang/Number
Elapsed 0.017931 ms for java/lang/Byte
Elapsed 0.017589 ms for java/lang/Short
Elapsed 0.017371 ms for java/lang/Integer
Elapsed 0.015637 ms for java/lang/Double
Elapsed 0.018173 ms for java/lang/String
Elapsed 0.015895 ms for java/math/BigDecimal
Elapsed 0.016204 ms for java/awt/Rectangle
Elapsed 0.016272 ms for java/awt/Point
Elapsed 0.001817 ms for java/lang/Object
Elapsed 0.016057 ms for java/lang/Class
Elapsed 0.016829 ms for java/net/URLClassLoader
Elapsed 0.017807 ms for java/lang/reflect/Field
Elapsed 0.016658 ms for java/util/Locale
Elapsed 0.015720 ms for java/lang/System
Elapsed 0.014669 ms for javax/swing/JTable
Elapsed 0.017276 ms for javax/swing/JComboBox
Elapsed 0.014777 ms for javax/swing/JList
Elapsed 0.015597 ms for java/awt/Component
Elapsed 0.015223 ms for javax/swing/JComponent
Elapsed 0.017385 ms for java/lang/Throwable
Elapsed 0.015089 ms for java/lang/StackTraceElement
```

The above values are from the Java event dispatcher thread. If I execute the same code in a native Windows thread that has been created by `CreateThread()` by me, it runs even **10 times faster**. Why?

So if you do not call `FindClass()` very frequently there is absolutely no problem calling it on demand when your JNI function is called instead of creating a global reference and storing it in a static variable.

---

Another important topic is **thread safety**. In Java each thread has it's own independent `JNIEnv` structure.

1. Global `jobject` or `jclass` are valid in any Java thread.
2. Local objects are only valid in one function call in the `JNIEnv` of the calling thread and are garbage collected when JNI code returns to Java.

Now it depends on the threads that you are using: If you register your C++ function with `env->RegisterNatives()` and Java code is calling into your JNI functions then you must store all objects, that you want to use later, as global objects otherwise they will get garbage collected.

But if you create your own thread with the `CraeteThread()` API (on Windows) and obtain the `JNIEnv` structure by calling `AttachCurrentThreadAsDaemon()` then completely other rules will apply: As it is your own thread, that never returns control to Java, the garbage collector will never clean up objects that you have created on your thread and you can even store local objects in static C++ variables without problems (but these cannot be accessed from other threads). In this case it is extremely important that you clean up ALL your local instances manually with `env->DeleteLocalRef()` otherwise you will have a memory leak. (However, the garbage collector probably frees all local objects when you call `DetachCurrentThread()`, which I never have tested.)

I strongly recommend to load ALL local objects into a wrapper class that calls `DeleteLocalRef()` in it's destructor. This is a bullet proof way to avoid memory leaks.

---

Developing JNI code may be very cumbersome and you may get crashes that you don't understand. To find the cause of a crash open a DOS window and start your Java application with the following command:

```
java -Xcheck:jni -jar MyApplication.jar
```

then you will see what problems have happened in JNI code. For example:

```
FATAL ERROR in native method: Bad global or local ref passed to JNI
```

and you will find the stacktrace in the log file that Java creates in the same folder where you have the JAR file:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6e8655d5, pid=4692, tid=4428
#
etc...
```

Comment: Certainly, as soon as they manage to complete my sign up ...

Answer (score 8):

Inside `JNI_OnLoad`, you need to use `NewGlobalRef` on the `jclass` values returned by `FindClass` before caching them.

Then, inside `JNI_OnUnload` you call `DeleteGlobalRef` on them.

Comment: JNI_OnLoad and JNI_OnUnload may not be called in pair, Unload is solely dependent on if GC has collected class loader. There is no reference to what i am going to say but logically speaking GC will ideally collect class loader when all the Global references are GCed, so there could be a memory leak in such case.

Answer (score 4):

As I remember jclass is will be local to the calling method so can't be cached, however the method id can be.  See http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html for more detaild info.

Sorry, I don't know about the performance aspect, any time I've used JNI it has been insignificant compared to the task in hand.

Answer (score 1):

You can cache and use your method/function/class IDs and safely use them if you code for it appropriately.  I have answered [a similar question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617735/in-jni-how-do-i-cache-the-class-methodid-and-fieldids-per-ibms-performance-r/13940735#13940735) and posted explicit code for how to follow IBM's caching performance recommendations.