# How to send a HashMap from Java to C via JNI

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, hashmap

I have an `Object` that has a `HashMap` field. When the `Object` is passed to C, how can I access the field?

The `Object`'s `Class` has the following fields:

```
private String hello;
private Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Comment: Basically, you'd pass it like any other object.  But to access it from C you need to invoke the Java methods of the class.

Answer (score 12):

The answer to your question really boils down to **why** you'd want to pass a `Map` to C rather than iterate your `Map` in Java and pass the contents to C. But, who am I to question why?

You ask how to access the `HashMap` (in your provided code, `Map`) field?  Write an accessor method for it in Java and call that accessor method from C when you pass the container `Object`.  Below is some bare-bones sample code showing how to pass a `Map` from Java to C, and how to access the `size()` method of the `Map`.  From it, you should be able to extrapolate how to call other methods.

Container Object:

```java
public class Container {

    private String hello;
    private Map<String, String> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public Map<String, String> getParameterMap() {
        return parameterMap;
    }
}
```

Master Class which passes a Container to JNI:

```java
public class MyClazz {

    public doProcess() {

        Container container = new Container();
        container.getParameterMap().put("foo","bar");

        manipulateMap(container);
    }

    public native void manipulateMap(Container container);
}
```

Relevant C function:

```c
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_MyClazz_manipulateMap(JNIEnv *env, jobject selfReference, jobject jContainer) {

    // initialize the Container class
    jclass c_Container = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, jContainer);

    // initialize the Get Parameter Map method of the Container class
    jmethodID m_GetParameterMap = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, c_Container, "getParameterMap", "()Ljava/util/Map;");

    // call said method to store the parameter map in jParameterMap
    jobject jParameterMap =  (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, jContainer, m_GetParameterMap);

    // initialize the Map interface
    jclass c_Map = env->FindClass("java/util/Map");

    // initialize the Get Size method of Map
    jmethodID m_GetSize = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, c_Map, "size", "()I");

    // Get the Size and store it in jSize; the value of jSize should be 1
    int jSize = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, jParameterMap, m_GetSize);

    // define other methods you need here.
}
```

Of note, I'm not crazy about initializing methodIDs and classes in the method itself; [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617735/in-jni-how-do-i-cache-the-class-methodid-and-fieldids-per-ibms-performance-r/13940735#13940735) shows you how to cache them for re-use.

Comment: Yeah, i have found a common solution for all complicated object conversion from Java to C, Very Thanks :-)

Comment: is it inefficient to call the hashmap methods from JNI ? I want to pass a properties object from java to the JNI layer. One idea is to directly call the the properties object's methods from JNI and other one is to convert the properties Map to key and value arrays in the java layer and pass the arrays to JNI native methods. Which one is efficient? or are there any alternative approaches I can consider ?