# Passing too many params from Java to c++ using JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

In Android app, I need to pass too many params (mostly integer or double values) from Java side to native side written in c++ and vice versa.
I have multiple algorithms written in c++, each needs set of params like  threshold, block and kernel size .. etc.

Currently I have 2 methods for each param in both sides for getting and setting its value but it is ugly and painful to maintain.

So **for each param** I have in Java:

```
private static native int nativeSetThreshold (final int threshold);

private static native int nativeGetThreshold();
```

And in header file c++:

```
void setThreshold(const int &threshold);

inline const int getThreshold() const { return mThreshold; };
```

Is there any better practice for this kind of communication?

Comment: Store the items in a Java class, and pass the instance of the class to the JNI layer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the problem is that I need to create the clas not only in a Java class but also in a curresponding c++ class

Comment: I do not know a best-practive, but I'd like you to consider passing a HashMap. A HashMap would enable you to get/set variables by name in both languages without having to explicitly define the variables in both languages. This SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16864286/2540235) says more about the idea.