# Returning an arraylist of string from Native java to JNI

Tags: java, arraylist, java-native-interface, native

```
ArrayList<String> myArraylist;          

public ArrayList<String> getData(){
    myArraylist = new ArrayList<String>();         
    myArraylist.add("1267982563");
    myArraylist.add("2345678");
    myArraylist.add("5432789");
    return myArraylist;
}
```

How to get the each items from the above method in JNI side and Push to vector and return from the JNI to other CPP calls in the JNI layer.

Comment: `"myArraylist<String>"` <-- that's not an `ArrayList<String>`. it's just a `String`.

Comment: If it's just an ArrayList of Strings, why not convert to a string array using toArray() and pass that to JNI as as a jobjectArray instead? Then you can use the JNI object array manipulation functions such as GetObjectArrayElement.

Comment: @SACH  You really should consider marking the below answer as the accepted solution, as it comprehensively solved your problem.

Answer (score 28):

**Convert ArrayList to std::vector<std::string>:**

```
jclass java_util_ArrayList;
jmethodID java_util_ArrayList_;
jmethodID java_util_ArrayList_size;
jmethodID java_util_ArrayList_get;
jmethodID java_util_ArrayList_add;
thread_local JNIEnv *env;

void init() {
  java_util_ArrayList      = static_cast<jclass>(env->NewGlobalRef(env->FindClass("java/util/ArrayList")));
  java_util_ArrayList_     = env->GetMethodID(java_util_ArrayList, "<init>", "(I)V");
  java_util_ArrayList_size = env->GetMethodID (java_util_ArrayList, "size", "()I");
  java_util_ArrayList_get  = env->GetMethodID(java_util_ArrayList, "get", "(I)Ljava/lang/Object;");
  java_util_ArrayList_add  = env->GetMethodID(java_util_ArrayList, "add", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z");
}

std::vector<std::string> java2cpp(jobject arrayList) {
  jint len = env->CallIntMethod(arrayList, java_util_ArrayList_size);
  std::vector<std::string> result;
  result.reserve(len);
  for (jint i=0; i<len; i++) {
    jstring element = static_cast<jstring>(env->CallObjectMethod(arrayList, java_util_ArrayList_get, i));
    const char *pchars = env->GetStringUTFChars(element, nullptr);
    result.emplace_back(pchars);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(element, pchars);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(element);
  }
}
```

**Push ArrayList from JNI back to Java**

If you don't modify this list in JNI, then the best strategy would be to simply keep a global reference to it somewhere in your native code. If you modify it a little, keep this **jobject** always up-to-date (you will probably need the methods **java_util_ArrayList_add** or **java_util_ArrayList_set**).

If you choose to reconstruct the list from <s>scratch</s> the vector, you will unwind the above method:

```
jobject cpp2java(std::vector<std::string> vector) {
  jobject result = env->NewObject(java_util_ArrayList, java_util_ArrayList_, vector.size());
  for (std::string s: vector) {
    jstring element = env->NewStringUTF(s.c_str());
    env->CallBooleanMethod(result, java_util_ArrayList_add, element);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(element);
  }
  return result;
}
```

At any rate, be careful with threads when you work with Jni, always attach your native threads and detach before the native thread is destroyed.

Comment: @AlexCohn Regarding your last sentence can you provide an example of this? For my case I want to pass the JNIEnv* pointer around from a native method to a helper method (in the same C++ file). It would essentially do what you're doing, except the cpp2java method for example would have a JNIEnv* pointer as an extra argument. Is this safe? Or what is your last sentence referring to exactly?

Comment: @ifma `JNIEnv*` is only valid on one thread. You can keep a `JavaVM*` and use `AttachThread()` to obtain a `JNIEnv*` for calls from C++ to Java, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12900986/192373.

Comment: @AlexCohn I appologise if this is obvious, but how can I set up a native file like the one in the first part of your answer in Android Studio? I set up a question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49466236/setting-up-jni-in-android-studio-3), I would appreciate any help

Comment: @AlexCohn great answer, thank you. Clang complains about the `static_cast<jstring>(...)`, advising "Do not use static_cast to downcast from a base to a derived class". I notice that `reinterpret_cast<jstring>(...)` works and Clang seems happy too. Is it okay to use `reinterpret_cast` instead?

Comment: @Pixel I believe that in this case, `static_cast` better expresses the programmer's intent. All C++ support having been added to JNI as an afterthought, the integration is never clean. The best approach I know is to disable the specific warning for each line where it pops up in the context of JNI *'classes'* `static_cast`.

Comment: @Pixel see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65764737/192373, it also shows how the complaint can be disabled.

Comment: Is this script of scope can really be global? I read another post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617735/in-jni-how-do-i-cache-the-class-methodid-and-fieldids-per-ibms-performance-r/13940735#13940735 showing a step using env->NewGlobalRef(....) once even announced static already

Comment: @Raii I don't understand your question. Method IDs are thread-independent constants. The `JNIEnv *` is per thread. `java_util_ArrayList` is a Java object. If you obtain a global reference, you can use it across threads and JNI calls, but the `FindClass` function returns a local reference, thus I call `NewGlobalRef`.