# How to properly use "C++ Core Guidelines: C.146: Use dynamic_cast where class hierarchy navigation is unavoidable"

Tags: c++, polymorphism, dynamic-cast, static-polymorphism, cpp-core-guidelines

## Motivation

The C++ Core Guidelines recommends using `dynamic_cast` when "class hierarchy navigation is unavoidable."  This triggers clang-tidy to throw the following error: `Do not use static_cast to downcast from a base to a derived class; use dynamic_cast instead [cppcoreguidelines-pro-type-static-cast-downcast]`.

The guidelines go on to say:

> #### [Note](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#note-157):
>
> Like other casts, `dynamic_cast` is overused. Prefer `virtual` functions
> to casting. Prefer static polymorphism to hierarchy navigation where
> it is possible (no run-time resolution necessary) and reasonably
> convenient.

I have always just used an `enum` named `Kind` nested in my base class, and performed a `static_cast` based on its kind.  Reading C++ Core Guidelines, "...Even so, in our experience such "I know what I'm doing" situations are still a known bug source." suggests that I should not be doing this.  Often, I don't have any `virtual` functions so RTTI is not present to use `dynamic_cast` (e.g. I will get `error: 'Base_discr' is not polymorphic`).  I can always add a `virtual` function, but that sounds silly.  The guideline also says to benchmark before considering using the discriminant approach that I use with `Kind`.

## [Benchmark](https://www.quick-bench.com/q/DwOMtGIsehbZFBosl1_VqDYQD1U)

```cpp
enum class Kind : unsigned char {
    A,
    B,
};


class Base_virt {
public:
    Base_virt(Kind p_kind) noexcept : m_kind{p_kind}, m_x{} {}

    [[nodiscard]] inline Kind
    get_kind() const noexcept {
        return m_kind;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] inline int
    get_x() const noexcept {
        return m_x;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] virtual inline int get_y() const noexcept = 0;

private:
    Kind const m_kind;
    int m_x;
};


class A_virt final : public Base_virt {
public:
    A_virt() noexcept : Base_virt{Kind::A}, m_y{} {}

    [[nodiscard]] inline int
    get_y() const noexcept final {
        return m_y;
    }

private:
    int m_y;
};


class B_virt : public Base_virt {
  public:
    B_virt() noexcept : Base_virt{Kind::B}, m_y{} {}

  private:
    int m_y;
};


static void
virt_static_cast(benchmark::State& p_state) noexcept {
    auto const a = A_virt();
    Base_virt const* ptr = &a;

    for (auto _ : p_state) {
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(static_cast<A_virt const*>(ptr)->get_y());
    }
}
BENCHMARK(virt_static_cast);


static void
virt_static_cast_check(benchmark::State& p_state) noexcept {
    auto const a = A_virt();
    Base_virt const* ptr = &a;

    for (auto _ : p_state) {
    if (ptr->get_kind() == Kind::A) {
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(static_cast<A_virt const*>(ptr)->get_y());
        } else {
            int temp = 0;
        }       
    }
}
BENCHMARK(virt_static_cast_check);


static void
virt_dynamic_cast_ref(benchmark::State& p_state) {
    auto const a = A_virt();
    Base_virt const& reff = a;

    for (auto _ : p_state) {
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(dynamic_cast<A_virt const&>(reff).get_y());
    }
}
BENCHMARK(virt_dynamic_cast_ref);


static void
virt_dynamic_cast_ptr(benchmark::State& p_state) noexcept {
    auto const a = A_virt();
    Base_virt const& reff = a;

    for (auto _ : p_state) {
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(dynamic_cast<A_virt const*>(&reff)->get_y());
    }
}
BENCHMARK(virt_dynamic_cast_ptr);


static void
virt_dynamic_cast_ptr_check(benchmark::State& p_state) noexcept {
    auto const a = A_virt();
    Base_virt const& reff = a;

    for (auto _ : p_state) {
        if (auto ptr = dynamic_cast<A_virt const*>(&reff)) {
            benchmark::DoNotOptimize(ptr->get_y());
        } else {
            int temp = 0;
        }
    }
}
BENCHMARK(virt_dynamic_cast_ptr_check);


class Base_discr {
public:
    Base_discr(Kind p_kind) noexcept : m_kind{p_kind}, m_x{} {}

    [[nodiscard]] inline Kind
    get_kind() const noexcept {
        return m_kind;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] inline int
    get_x() const noexcept {
        return m_x;
    }

private:
    Kind const m_kind;
    int m_x;
};


class A_discr final : public Base_discr {
public:
    A_discr() noexcept : Base_discr{Kind::A}, m_y{} {}

    [[nodiscard]] inline int
    get_y() const noexcept {
        return m_y;
    }

private:
    int m_y;
};


class B_discr : public Base_discr {
public:
    B_discr() noexcept : Base_discr{Kind::B}, m_y{} {}

private:
    int m_y;
};


static void
discr_static_cast(benchmark::State& p_state) noexcept {
    auto const a = A_discr();
    Base_discr const* ptr = &a;

    for (auto _ : p_state) {
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(static_cast<A_discr const*>(ptr)->get_y());
    }
}
BENCHMARK(discr_static_cast);


static void
discr_static_cast_check(benchmark::State& p_state) noexcept {
    auto const a = A_discr();
    Base_discr const* ptr = &a;

    for (auto _ : p_state) {
        if (ptr->get_kind() == Kind::A) {
            benchmark::DoNotOptimize(static_cast<A_discr const*>(ptr)->get_y());
        } else {
            int temp = 0;
        }
    }
}
BENCHMARK(discr_static_cast_check);
```

I am new to benchmarking, so I don't really know what I am doing.  I took care to make sure that `virtual` and discriminant versions have the same memory layout and tried my best to prevent optimizations.  I went with optimization level `O1` since anything higher didn't seem representative. `discr` stands for discriminated or tagged. `virt` stands for `virtual`  Here are my results:

[image: Benchmark Results]

## Questions

So, my questions are: How should I cast from a base to a derived type when (1) I know the derived type because I checked it before entering the function and (2) when I do not know the derived type yet. Additionally, (3) Should I even be worried about this guideline, or should I disable the warning?  Performance matters here, but sometimes it does not.  What should I be using?

## EDIT:

Using `dynamic_cast` seems to be the [correct](https://youtu.be/ARYP83yNAWk?t=206) answer for downcasting.  However, you still need to know what you are downcasting to and have a `virtual` function.  In many cases, you do not know without a discriminate such as `kind` or `tag` what the derived class is.  (4) In the case where I already have to check what the `kind` of object I am looking at, should I still be using `dynamic_cast`? Is this not checking the same thing twice? (5) Is there a reasonable way to do this without a `tag`?

### [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/7dvozq)

Consider the `class` hierarchy:

```
class Expr {
public:
    enum class Kind : unsigned char {
        Int_lit_expr,
        Neg_expr,
        Add_expr,
        Sub_expr,
    };

    [[nodiscard]] Kind
    get_kind() const noexcept {
        return m_kind;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] bool
    is_unary() const noexcept {
        switch(get_kind()) {
            case Kind::Int_lit_expr:
            case Kind::Neg_expr:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    [[nodiscard]] bool
    is_binary() const noexcept {
        switch(get_kind()) {
            case Kind::Add_expr:
            case Kind::Sub_expr:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

protected:
    explicit Expr(Kind p_kind) noexcept : m_kind{p_kind} {}

private:
    Kind const m_kind;
};


class Unary_expr : public Expr {
public:
    [[nodiscard]] Expr const*
    get_expr() const noexcept {
        return m_expr;
    }

protected:
    Unary_expr(Kind p_kind, Expr const* p_expr) noexcept :
        Expr{p_kind},
        m_expr{p_expr} {}

private:
    Expr const* const m_expr;
};


class Binary_expr : public Expr {
public:
    [[nodiscard]] Expr const*
    get_lhs() const noexcept {
        return m_lhs;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] Expr const*
    get_rhs() const noexcept {
        return m_rhs;
    }

protected:
    Binary_expr(Kind p_kind, Expr const* p_lhs, Expr const* p_rhs) noexcept :
        Expr{p_kind},
        m_lhs{p_lhs},
        m_rhs{p_rhs} {}

private:
    Expr const* const m_lhs;
    Expr const* const m_rhs;
};


class Add_expr : public Binary_expr {
public:
    Add_expr(Expr const* p_lhs, Expr const* p_rhs) noexcept : 
        Binary_expr{Kind::Add_expr, p_lhs, p_rhs} {}
};
```

Now in `main()`:

```
int main() {
    auto const add = Add_expr{nullptr, nullptr};
    Expr const* const expr_ptr = &add;

    if (expr_ptr->is_unary()) {
        auto const* const expr = static_cast<Unary_expr const* const>(expr_ptr)->get_expr();
    } else if (expr_ptr->is_binary()) {
        // Here I use a static down cast after checking it is valid
        auto const* const lhs = static_cast<Binary_expr const* const>(expr_ptr)->get_lhs();
    
        // error: cannot 'dynamic_cast' 'expr_ptr' (of type 'const class Expr* const') to type 'const class Binary_expr* const' (source type is not polymorphic)
        // auto const* const rhs = dynamic_cast<Binary_expr const* const>(expr_ptr)->get_lhs();
    }
}
```

```
<source>:99:34: warning: do not use static_cast to downcast from a base to a derived class [cppcoreguidelines-pro-type-static-cast-downcast]

        auto const* const expr = static_cast<Unary_expr const* const>(expr_ptr)->get_expr();

                                 ^
```

Not always will I need to cast to an `Add_expr`.  For example, I could have a function that prints out any `Binary_expr`.  It only need to cast it to `Binary_expr` to get the `lhs` and `rhs`.  To get the symbol of the operator (e.g. '-' or '+' ...) it can switch on the `kind`.  I don't see how `dynamic_cast` will help me here and I also have no virtual functions to use `dynamic_cast` on.

## EDIT 2:

I have posted an answer making `get_kind()` `virtual`, this seems to be a good solution in general.  However, I am now carrying around 8 bytes for a `vtbl_ptr` instead of a byte for a tag.  Object instantiated from `class`es derived from `Expr` will far exceed any other object types.  (6) Is this a good time to skip the `vtbl_ptr` or should I prefer the safety of `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: for the first question: If you checked before the function and you know it is of derived type, then why does the function take a reference to base?

Comment: "I am new to benchmarking, so I don't really know what I am doing. I ... tried my best to prevent optimizations.".  C++ without optimizations is used to debug code, but the resulting performance is meaningless. That's generally no big problem as the human debugging is the slowest component.

Comment: If you don't have `virtual` and you `static_cast` from parent to child, I would be suspicious. Looks like composition would be better and the cast is also avoidable. If you know the type before entering the function, cast it before entering the function. if you don't know the derived type yet, then RTTI (with virtual...)/dynamic_cast is a solution, you can also use static_cast as it's faster. That's where you have to draw the line.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher, So I have been casting before entering the function, but that just moves the problem to what cast to use before entering the function.

Comment: @MSalters, If I use higher optimizations, it optimizes the program away.  The compiler simply has to much information for this example.  What if I am casting from a `Expr` to `Binary_expr` or `Add_expr`.  No `virtual` functions at in the hierarchy.

Comment: @user1032677: So, what you discovered is that in real-world environments the operations can take 0.0 seconds. That shows how well the optimizer understands what `dynamic_cast` does.

Comment: @MSalters I mean the object was declared on the previous line.  It's not going to make that optimization if it came from the free store where it can't know which function created the object, which is more likely in my case

Comment: Well, then benchmark what you are trying to benchmark. That particular optimization is real and useful. For users that follow the guideline which started the question, it means they don't have a runtime penalty when the compiler can avoid it.

Comment: @MSalters You were right: https://youtu.be/ARYP83yNAWk?t=206

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher @MSalters I edited the question with and what I am truly trying to do.  I have no `virtual` functions, yet I want to downcast.  Any thoughts?

Comment: My view is, if you don't have a `virtual` but want to downcast, then you have a design problem. Maybe there is a complex reason why you want to do this, but if you have to ask this question, it means you don't have the required skill to do it and thus you shouldn't use this design. Composition seems to be more adequate.

Comment: @Matthieu Brucher, What about in my `Expr` example where the `vtbl_ptr`  takes up 50% of the objects memory layout for a `Unary_expr`? Classes deriving from `Expr` (or similar such as `Type`) will be the most instantiated objects.  CRTP seems to solve this, but I will still need to be able to use a pointer to the base case. @xryl669 answer suggests using a `virtual` function to tag it, but that kinda ruins the point (or am I missing something?).  Since all of the objects I allocate will be only several bytes, I am not certain the `vptr` is a good trade off even if its fast.

Comment: @user1032677: "*What about in my Expr example where the vtbl_ptr takes up 50% of the objects memory layout for a Unary_expr?*" Why is `Expr` a base class rather than some form of variant type, where the possibilities are clearly specified? This is probably what Matthieu was talking about with "a design problem": that there are *better* ways to do the thing you're trying to do than using inheritance. Your `Expr` class could easily be a `std::variant<BinaryOp, Literal>`, where `BinaryOp` is a struct that contains two other sub-expressions and a value telling which operation it performs.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I see what you are saying, and that is very useful.  However, in my case I have about 40 different `kind`s.  `gtoe_expr`, `modulo_assignment_expr`, `double_lit_expr`.  Am I really expected to pack this all into a `std::variant`?

Comment: @user1032677: There's a reason why I ignored your several types and broke them down into two: a binary operator (which represents *any* binary operator, with a particular instance storing the specific type of operator) and a literal terminal value. You don't need a separate type for every kind of binary operator. You are overusing OOP, which is typically what has happened when you start wanting to downcast like that.

Comment: @NicolBolas, So I will still use a tag (one `enum class` for `Unary_expr`, another for `Binary_expr`, ...).  That's an acceptable answer. Thanks!

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes indeed, thanks for explaining better! @user#032677 I think you need to practice a little bit more, take some steps back, experiment with different other problems before coming back to this one and enhance the design properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the important part of this guideline is the part about "where class hierarchy navigation is unavoidable". The basic point here being that, if you're *wanting* to do this kind of casting a lot, then odds are good that there is something wrong with your design. Either you picked the wrong way to do something or you designed yourself into a corner.

Overuse of OOP is one example of such a thing. Let's take your example of `Expr`, which is a node in an expression tree. And you can ask it questions like whether it is a binary operation, unary operation, or a nullary operation (FYI: literal values are nullary, not unary. They take no arguments).

Where you've overused OOP was in trying to give each operator its own class type. What is the difference between an addition operator and a multiplication operator? Precedence? That's a matter for the grammar; it's irrelevant once you've built the expression tree. The only operation that really cares about the specific binary operator is when you evaluate it. And even when doing evaluation, the only part that's special is when you take the results of the evaluation of the operands and feed it into the code that's going to produce the result of this operation. Everything else is the same for all binary operations.

So you have one function that is different for various binary operations. If there's just one function that changes, you really don't need different types just for that. It's much more reasonable for the different binary operators to be different values within a general `BinaryOp` class. The same goes for `UnaryOp` and `NullaryOp`s.

So within this example, there are only 3 possible types for any given node. And that's very reasonable to deal with as a `variant<NullaryOp, UnaryOp, BinaryOp>`. So an `Expr` can just contain one of those, with each operand type having zero or more pointers to its child `Expr` elements. There could be a generic interface on `Expr` for getting the number of children, iterating through the children, etc. And the different `Op` types can provide the implementations for these through simple visitors.

Most cases when you start to want to do downcasting and such things are cases that can be solved better and more cleanly using other mechanisms. If you're building hierarchies without `virtual` functions, where code receiving base classes already knows most or all of the possible derived classes, odds are good that you're really writing a crude form of `variant`.

Comment: So in the most basic form `Expr*` points to a `std::variant`?

Comment: A potential design flaw with this method is that you are repeating yourself.  The `variant` stores information for the arity of the expression, but each kind of expression family will need a `kind` tag to tell you if you are looking at an addition or subtraction expression.  If my `kind` tag says it is `addition` then I know it's a `Binary_expr`.  Doesn't this go against the DRY principal and use more memory than necessary?

Comment: @user1032677: I don't see how this relates to DRY. The questions "is this a binary operation" and "what kind of binary operation is it" are two separate questions, asked by two separate places in code, which have two separate responses, leading to two separate uses. The question of memory consumption is too trivial to bother looking into; even if you have an expression tree with a 100,000 nodes, you're talking about less than 512KB of "more memory".

Comment: By not inheriting from `Expr`, am I not misusing the "Is-A" relationship?

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in the Curious Recursing Template Pattern here to avoid the need for virtual method at all if you know the type of the instance at compile time

```
template <typename Impl> 
class Base_virt {
public:
    Base_virt(Kind p_kind) noexcept : m_kind{p_kind}, m_x{} {}

    [[nodiscard]] inline Kind
    get_kind() const noexcept { return Impl::kind(); }

    [[nodiscard]] inline int
    get_x() const noexcept {
        return m_x;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] inline int get_y() const noexcept { 
        return static_cast<const Impl*>(this)->get_y(); 
    }

private:
    int m_x;
};


class A_virt final : public Base_virt<A_virt> {
public:
    A_virt() noexcept : Base_virt{Kind::A}, m_y{} {}

    [[nodiscard]] inline static Kind kind() { return Kind::A; }

    [[nodiscard]] inline int
    get_y() const noexcept final {
        return m_y;
    }

private:
    int m_y;
};

// Copy/paste/rename for B_virt
```

In that case, there is no need for dynamic_cast at all since everything is known at compile time. You are loosing the possibility to store a pointer to `Base_virt` (unless you create a `BaseTag` base class that `Base_virt` derives from)
The code to call such method must then be template:

```
template <typename Impl>
static void
crtp_cast_check(benchmark::State& p_state) noexcept {
    auto const a = A_virt();
    Base_virt<Impl> const* ptr = &a;

    for (auto _ : p_state) {
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(ptr->get_y());
    }
}
BENCHMARK(crtp_static_cast_check<A_virt>);
```

This is likely be compiled to a strait call to `for(auto _ : p_state) b::dno(m_y)`.
The incovenient of this approach is the inflated binary space (you'll have as many instance of the function as there are child types), but it'll be the fastest since the compiler will deduce the type at compile time.

With a `BaseTag` approach, it'll look like:

```
   class BaseTag { virtual Kind get_kind() const = 0; }; 
   // No virtual destructor here, since you aren't supposed to manipulate instance via this type

   template <typename Impl>
   class Base_virt : BaseTag { ... same as previous definition ... };

   // Benchmark method become
   void virt_bench(BaseTag & base) {
     // This is the only penalty with a virtual method:
     switch(base.get_kind()) {

       case Kind::A : static_cast<A_virt&>(base).get_y(); break;
       case Kind::B : static_cast<B_virt&>(base).get_y(); break;
       ...etc...
       default: assert(false); break; // At least you'll get a runtime error if you forget to update this table for new Kind
     }
     // In that case, there is 0 advantage not to make get_y() virtual, but
     // if you have plenty of "pseudo-virtual" method, it'll become more 
     // interesting to consult the virtual table only once for get_kind 
     // instead of for each method
   }

   template <typename Class>
   void static_bench(Class & inst) {
     // Lame code:
     inst.get_y();
   }

   A_virt a;
   B_virt b;

   virt_bench(a);
   virt_bench(b);

   // vs
   static_bench(a);
   static_bench(b);
```

*Sorry for pseudo code above, but you'll get the idea.*

Notice that mixing dynamic inheritance and static inheritance like the above makes code maintenance a burden (if you add a new type, you'll need to fix all your **switch table**), so it must be reserved for very small performance sensitive parts of your code.

Comment: The `BaseTag` approach seems equivalent to my `Kind` approach except that `get_kind()` is now `virtual`.  After learning about the downcast optimization of `dynamic_cast`, it would appear that it will always be as good as checking a `tag` and then `static_cast`ing based on that.

Comment: Yes, but if you are chaining your code with a succession of *dynamic_cast* (`if dc<A> else if dc<B> else if dc<C> etc..`) then you'll pay the virtual test X times (since you can't switch on the type in C++), while with the BaseTag & Kind approad, you can.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to make `get_kind()` a `virtual` function.  You can then use `dynamic_cast`.  If you are going to be calling a lot of `virtual` functions, you can downcast it to the most derived class so that the optimizer can optimize out the `virtual` calls.  You will also want to use `virtual` inheritance (e.g. `class Unary_expr : public virtual Expr {};` if you do not have any data members in the base class to properly use memory.  Having a pointer to the `vtable` takes up 8 bytes on a 64-bit machine, so you may be forced to use a discriminate to cut down on the size of each object (but this obviously only makes sense if absolutely no `virtual` functions will be used).

This method solves the following issue raised in the guidlines:

> ...Even so, in our experience such "I know what I'm doing" situations are still a known bug source.

@xryl669 points out that the "curious recursing template pattern" or CRTP can be used to remove the need of checking the type at runtime if you know what type you are dealing with.  He covers a problem and solution of the method too, so you should definatly check his answer out too.

Here is another resource on CRTP I found useful: [The cost of dynamic (virtual calls) vs. static (CRTP) dispatch in C++](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/12/05/the-cost-of-dynamic-virtual-calls-vs-static-crtp-dispatch-in-c)

```cpp
class Expr {
public:
    enum class Kind : unsigned char {
        Int_lit_expr,
        Neg_expr,
        Add_expr,
        Sub_expr,
    };

    [[nodiscard]] virtual Kind get_kind() const noexcept = 0;

    [[nodiscard]] virtual bool
    is_unary() const noexcept {
        return false;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] virtual bool
    is_binary() const noexcept {
        return false;
    }
};


class Unary_expr : public virtual Expr {
public:
    [[nodiscard]] bool
    is_unary() const noexcept final {
        return true;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] Expr const*
    get_expr() const noexcept {
        return m_expr;
    }

protected:
    explicit Unary_expr(Expr const* p_expr) noexcept : m_expr{p_expr} {}

private:
    Expr const* const m_expr;
};


class Binary_expr : public virtual Expr {
public:
    [[nodiscard]] bool
    is_binary() const noexcept final {
        return true;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] Expr const*
    get_lhs() const noexcept {
        return m_lhs;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] Expr const*
    get_rhs() const noexcept {
        return m_rhs;
    }

protected:
    Binary_expr(Expr const* p_lhs, Expr const* p_rhs) noexcept : m_lhs{p_lhs}, m_rhs{p_rhs} {}

private:
    Expr const* const m_lhs;
    Expr const* const m_rhs;
};


class Add_expr final : public Binary_expr {
public:
    Add_expr(Expr const* p_lhs, Expr const* p_rhs) noexcept : Binary_expr{p_lhs, p_rhs} {}

    [[nodiscard]] Kind get_kind() const noexcept final {
        return Kind::Add_expr;
    }
};


int main() {
    auto const add = Add_expr{nullptr, nullptr};
    Expr const* const expr_ptr = &add;

    if (expr_ptr->is_unary()) {
        // NOLINTNEXTLINE(clang-analyzer-deadcode.DeadStores): it is just an example
        auto const* const expr = dynamic_cast<Unary_expr const* const>(expr_ptr)->get_expr();

    } else if (expr_ptr->is_binary()) {
        // NOLINTNEXTLINE(clang-analyzer-deadcode.DeadStores): it is just an example
        auto const* const lhs = dynamic_cast<Binary_expr const* const>(expr_ptr)->get_lhs();
    
        // NOLINTNEXTLINE(clang-analyzer-deadcode.DeadStores): it is just an example
        auto const* const rhs = dynamic_cast<Binary_expr const* const>(expr_ptr)->get_lhs();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All these arguments are wonderful, but there are some cases where these solutions cannot be applied. One example is the seasoned JNI spec. Sony added C++ wrapper to the official Java Native Interface as an afterthought. For example, they define `GetObjectField()` method that returns `jobject`. But if the *field* is an array, you must *cast* it down to `jbyteArray`, e.g. to be able to use `GetArrayLength()`.

It is impossible to use **dynamic_cast** with JNI. The alternatives are either **C-style** cast, or **static_cast**, and I believe that the latter is safer, or at least, cleaner than

```
(jbyteArray)env->CallObjectMethod(myObject, toByteArray_MethodID);
```

To suppress the warning in Android Studio for a single line, use `NOLINT`:

```
auto byteArray = static_cast<jbyteArray>(env->CallObjectMethod(myObject, toByteArray_MethodID)); // NOLINT(cppcoreguidelines-pro-type-static-cast-downcast)
```

Or, set

```
#pragma ide diagnostic ignored "cppcoreguidelines-pro-type-static-cast-downcast"
```

for a file or block