# jmethodID in android ART

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I'm working on an app.
Inside JNI_OnLoad():

```
jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "dummy/dummy/dummy/Dummy");
    if(cls == NULL) {
        LOG_ERROR("unable to class");
        return;
    }

    cached_dummy.cls = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, cls);
    if(cached_dummy.cls == NULL) {
        LOG_ERROR("unable to create a global reference of class");
        return;
    }

    cached_dummy.method = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, cls, "testMethod", "()V");
```

and when i used this cached result in java callback using `(*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, cached_dummy.cls, cached_dummy.method)`

Result: "JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: jmethodID was NULL"
Android 5.0.2
Query:
 Incompatibility?
 Solution? (Do i need to make a global reference of jmethodID?)

Note: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2093300/1500988

Comment: Did you check what `GetStaticMethodID` returned?

Comment: @immibis is returning non-NULL. found the culprit :)

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with recursive loading of shared library.

when class is loaded, its static block is executed.
Inside the static block, shared library loader is placed on top and then rest of init code.

class(Foo) load => its static block executed => jni library loader => JNI_OnLoad => cache static method Foo.Bar() => class(Foo) load => WARN(recusive-load-warning) and execute the rest static block remaining code that call jni code and it uses Foo.Bar() and BOOM!