# Unable to set Java int array field from JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm developing an Android App and I'm receiving camera data from a lib in C++. I need to send this data from C++ to the Java code. For this, I'm using JNI. I'm able to set different fields in Java from the JNI and the C++ data (like the name or the type of the camera), but I'm unable to set the ID Field because it's an `uint8_t` array.

How can I do this?

I already tried several ways to do this but each time I've got an `SIGSEGV error` with an invalid address. For others fields I'm using

```cpp
env->Set<Primitives>Field(jobject, jfieldID, value)
```

method but there are no methods like that for `int` array, are there?
So, I've tried to set this field by calling a method from my class and provide the `int` array as parameter but this function failed and returned the `SIGSEGV error`.

Then, I searched on the web and I tried to set the field through

```cpp
env->GetObjectField(jobject, jfieldID)
```

and

```cpp
env->SetIntArrayRegion(jintArray, start, end, myIntArray)
```

but here the first method returns always null.

```cpp
JavaVM * mJVM; //My Java Virtual Machine
jobject mCameraObject, mThreadObject; //Previously initialize to call functions in the right thread

void onReceiveCameraList(void *ptr, uint32_t /*id*/, my::lib::Camera *arrayCamera, uint32_t nbCameras) {

    JNIEnv *env;
    mJVM->AttachCurrentThread(&env, nullptr);
    if (env->ExceptionCheck())
        return;

    //Get Field, Method ID, Object and Class
    jclass cameraClass = env->GetObjectClass(mCameraObject);

    jfieldID camIDField = env->GetFieldID(cameraClass, "idCam", "[I");
    jfieldID camNameField = env->GetFieldID(cameraClass, "label", "Ljava/lang/String;");
    jfieldID camConnectedField = env->GetFieldID(cameraClass, "connected", "Z");
    jfieldID camTypeField = env->GetFieldID(cameraClass, "typeProduit", "B");

    jmethodID camReceptionMID = env->GetMethodID(env->GetObjectClass(mThreadObject), "onCamerasReception", "([Lcom/my/path/models/Camera;)V"); //Java function
    jobjectArray cameraArray = env->NewObjectArray(nbCameras, cameraClass, mCameraObject); //Object return in the functions

    //Put the cameras into the vector
    std::vector<my::lib::Camera> vectorCameras;
    if(!vectorCameras.empty())
        vectorCameras.clear();

    if ((arrayCamera != nullptr) && (nbCameras > 0)) {
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < nbCameras; ++i) {
            vectorCameras.push_back(arrayCamera[i]);
        }
    }

    //Set the my::lib::Camera field into Java::Camera
    int c= 0;
    for (auto & cam : vectorCameras)
    {
        jobject camera = env->AllocObject(cameraClass); //Object Camera to add in cameraArray object

    // MY DATA TO SET ID FIELD ///
    jint idArray[16];
        for (int i = 0; i < 16 ; ++i) {
            idArray[i] = cam.idCamera.data[i]; // uint8_t cam.idCamera.data[16]
        }

    ///////// FIRST WAY  /////////
    jmethodID setIDCamMID = env->GetMethodID(env->GetObjectClass(camera), "setIDCam", "([I)V");
    env->CallVoidMethod(camera, setIDCamMID, idArray);

    ///////// SECOND WAY /////////
        jintArray jintArray1 = (jintArray)env->GetObjectField(camera, camIDField);
        env->SetIntArrayRegion(jintArray1, 0, 16, idArray);

    //Set<Primitives>Field : WORKING
        env->SetObjectField(camera, camNameField, env->NewStringUTF((const char *) cam.labelCamera));
        env->SetBooleanField(camera, camConnectedField, cam.isCameraConnected);
        jbyte type;
        if (cam.typeCamera == my::lib::TYPE_1 || cam.typeCamera == my::lib::TYPE_2 || cam.typeCamera == my::lib::TYPE_3) //type not known in JAVA
            type = 0;
        else
            type = cam.typeCamera;
        env->SetByteField(camera, camTypeField, type);

    //Put camera object into cameraArray object
        env->SetObjectArrayElement(cameraArray, c++, camera);
    }//for

    //Call Java method with cameraArray
    env->CallVoidMethod(mThreadObject, camReceptionMID, dpCameraArray);

}//onreceiveCamera
```

Can someone tell me if I made a mistake or am using it the wrong way?
Is there any other way to set this data?

Comment: Are you checking **all** your calls such as `jclass cameraClass = env->GetObjectClass(mCameraObject);` to ensure that they actually work?  Outside of your initial check for an exception, your code does no error checking and can fail badly without you knowing it.  Because caching objects like you do with with `jobject mCameraObject, mThreadObject; //Previously initialize to call functions in the right thread` can cause problems if not done properly.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093112/why-i-should-not-reuse-a-jclass-and-or-jmethodid-in-jni

Comment: *ID Field is an uint8_t array*  — that's what you have on the C++ side of your JNI. But how is the field declared in Java?

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes, it was the first point I checked, all are initialized and work correctly

Comment: @AlexCohn in the JAva side, it's declare as `int[] idCamera = new int[16];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This yields a C++ array with elements of type `jint`:

> ```
>     // MY DATA TO SET ID FIELD ///
>     jint idArray[16];
>         for (int i = 0; i < 16 ; ++i) {
>             idArray[i] = cam.idCamera.data[i]; // uint8_t cam.idCamera.data[16]
>         }
> ```

It is important to understand that **that is not a *Java* array**.  Therefore, this ...

> ```
>     ///////// FIRST WAY  /////////
>     jmethodID setIDCamMID = env->GetMethodID(env->GetObjectClass(camera), "setIDCam", "([I)V");
>     env->CallVoidMethod(camera, setIDCamMID, idArray);
> ```

... is incorrect.  `idArray` is not the right type (and does not decay to a pointer to the right type) for the corresponding parameter to the Java method you are trying to invoke.

On the other hand, this ...

> ```
>     ///////// SECOND WAY /////////
>         jintArray jintArray1 = (jintArray)env->GetObjectField(camera, camIDField);
>         env->SetIntArrayRegion(jintArray1, 0, 16, idArray);
> ```

... is ok, *provided that the field already contains a reference to an `int[]` of length at least 16*.  Since it didn't work for you, I take it that the field's initial value does not satisfy that criterion.

**If you need to create a *new* Java `int[]`**, then

1. use JNI's `NewIntArray()` function, which returns a `jintArray` with the length you specify.  Then
2. use the appropriate JNI methods for setting the elements (see below), and finally
3. either assign the array directly to the target object's field with `SetObjectField()` or use the object's setter method to do so, as in your first attempt.

As for setting elements of the Java array, `SetIntArrayRegion()` will work fine for that (given an actual Java array of sufficient length), but that does require you to allocate a separate native array of primitives (your `idArray`) from which to copy the values.  A slightly more efficient approach would be to use `GetPrimitiveArrayCritical()` to let Java provide the buffer -- possibly a direct pointer to the internal data -- and then `ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical()` when you're done.  Something like this:

```
// It is assumed here that the length of the array is sufficient, perhaps because
// we just created this (Java) array.
jint *idArray = (jint *) env->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(jintArray1, NULL);

for (uint32_t i = 0; i < nbCameras; ++i) {
    idArray[i] = cam.idCamera.data[i];
}
env->ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(jintArray1, idArray, 0);
```

Comment: As I remarked in my answer, the use of `AllocObject` results in an object with default values for fields, including `null` for the camId field. Had OP used `NewObject`, this was the constructor's responsibility.

Comment: Thanks, yours answers are really instructive. It is working now!

Comment: That's a good observation about `AllocObject`, @Botje.  We can be *confident* that the object's fields have default values for their types, since it has not been initialized.  But of course, even if it had been initialized, it is not necessarily the case that the field in question would contain a reference to a suitable array.

Answer (score 3):

For the first approach, you need to create a Java `int[]` first, fill it from `idArray`, and *then* call your method:

```cpp
jintArray j_arr = env->NewIntArray(16);
env->SetIntArrayRegion(j_arr, 0, 16, idArray);
env->CallVoidMethod(camera, setIDCamMID, j_arr);
```

Your second approach does not work because you never called a constructor that filled the `idCam` field.
You can do that from JNI, however:

```cpp
env->SetObjectField(camera, camIDField, j_arr);
```